# How to Achieve filters while mapping entity to table?

Tags: jpa, entity, filtering

As it is mentioned in this document

> http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Filters

How to acheive filtering data?This is nothing to do with inheritance.I want to restrict my object mapping to only subset of rows based on some condition.

Comment: Think it as a case of soft delete.

Comment: As mentioned in the article, some JPA implementation provide proprietary support for this. There's nothing standard. Read the doc of your JPA implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard JPA support for this.

If you are using EclipseLink, you can either use @AdditionalCriteria, or @Multitenent,

see,

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_additionalcriteria.htm#additionalcriteria

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_multitenant.htm#BABIEJGD

You could also use a view in the database.